# Python-Docx: How to identify whether a paragraph is italicized

Tags: python, python-docx

So, hypothetically, I have this code:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document(r'C:\example.docx')
run_list = []

for p in doc.paragraphs:
   for run in p.runs:
      if not run.italic:
         run_list.append(run.text)
```

It will now accurately add all non-italicized runs to run_list, and skips all italicized runs. However, if the entire paragraph is italicized, rather than just one run, `run.italic` will return `False`. There is no `paragraph.italic` method, so I'm wondering how to also skip all italicized paragraphs?

Comment: What is *doc* ?

Comment: doc is the document that the method is applied to (so example.docx, for example)

Comment: Still not enough code to explain what you're doing. What is *docx* ?

Comment: If it is a latex text then you could check with the condition `== "*"` then it means that the following paragraph will be  italicized. However we definitely do not have much information but the idea of checking star Is maybe one of the best trick you could have so far now..

Comment: This is regarding the python-docx module; as apparent from the title...

Comment: It's a Word document, unfortunately.

Comment: @Voxel Now with this code it makes more sense sorry I was confused that is why I answer a broad comment. Will answer.

Comment: @Voxel After re reading, what would you like to do is to automatically skip a paragraph if all his content is italic right? If so it would let you having a faster loop if you could avoid checking every runs, is it your wish ?

Comment: This is simplified code that just tries to highlight the problem I'm having; the normal code looks for a pipeline character in the word document and adds a picture below it. It's meant to skip a picture if an italicized pipeline character is found. And that should include pipelines in paragraphs that are fully italicized.

Comment: Check `paragraph.style`, which could be set to a style with italicized text.

Comment: `paragraph.style` unfortunately returns the style `"normal"` for all paragraphs. Interestingly even for those which I've applied a special style - like `"title"` - to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of digging, it seems I've run into a limitation of python-docx. There's a difference between explicit styles (i.e. what's directly applied to a run) and effective styles (i.e. what's being displayed as a result of style hierarchies) The paragraph that failed to work had the 'Subtle Emphasis' style applied to it. This style told Word to apply italics to the whole paragraph; therefore, individual runs did not have it assigned.

To *some* degree, it's possible to counteract this by comparing paragraph.style.name. Outside of that, though, python-docx is unable to evaluate *effective* styles.

Further reading: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/font.html

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html